# Need to loop through 2 arrays at the same time in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have two arrays that I need to loop through. Using `foreach`, I can only loop through one at a time. A regular `for(i = 0; i<7; i++)` Loop would be great.

Comment: Have you tried nested `foreach` loops?

Comment: nested would mean it loops through the inner loop, and then the outer loop...

Comment: Although I think that skaffman has it right, posting a "raw" Java example of what you'd like to achieve in JSTL flavor would be helpful to get the picture. Also, your previous comment sounds more like an argue to skaffman's comment. If it's actually a *question* (how to achieve that), you should have put a question mark instead of three dots. Else that comment makes not much sense.

Answer (score 11):

I think I see what you mean - you have two arrays (probably of equal size), and you want to loop so that you use the loop index to access each array.

If that's what you meant (and it's far from clear from your question), then you could do something like this (assuming `arrayX` and `arrayY`).

```
<c:forEach items="${arrayX}" varStatus="loop">
    <c:out value="${arrayX[loop.index]}"/>
    <c:out value="${arrayY[loop.index]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This uses `arrayX` to get the iterator, but then uses indexed lookups into `arrayX` and `arrayY`.

`varStatus` is described [here](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2009/04/jstl-foreach-looping-tricks-using.html) .

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Collections?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something from [*JSTL in Action*](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/jstl/):

```
 <c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="current">
    <c:out value="${current}"/>
</c:forEach>
```